# Access children of embedded aswf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, embedding

I am embedding an swf file that has some children on its timeline. Like this:

```
[Embed(source="assets/skyscraper200x600.swf")]
private var Skyscraper  :Class;
```

All children in the swf have an instance name, I double checked that when creating the swf in Flash CS5.
I am trying to access those children by name like this:

```
_bg = MovieClip(new Skyscraper());
_pig = MovieClip(_bg.getChildByName("chara_pig"));
_arrow = MovieClip(_bg.getChildByName("arrow_banner"));
```

However, both _pig and _arrow end up being null.

What's even stranger is that when I look at the Skyscraper object in the debugger, it shows a rather strange class name and a Loader as its only child (which in turn has no children). What's up with this?

.

I **can** access them like above if I do not embed the swf, but load it with a Loader. But I cannot do it in this case. I need to embed the swf.

So, how can you access children of embedded swfs?

I am **not** talking about accessing classes in the library of the embedded swf, but the instances on the timeline.

Comment: It was, at first. But we switched it to be AS3. Unfortunately, that didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution. You can also see the steps who helped me find this solution (describeType is your friend) :

```
public class Demo extends Sprite {

    [Embed(source="test.swf")]
    private var Test:Class

    public function Demo() {
        //first guess is that embed SWF is a MovieClip
        var embedSWF:MovieClip = new Test() as MovieClip;
        addChild(embedSWF);

        //well, emebed SWF is more than just a MovieClip...       
        trace(describeType(embedSWF));//mx.core::MovieClipLoaderAsset
        trace(embedSWF.numChildren);//1
        trace(describeType(embedSWF.getChildAt(0)));//flash.display::Loader

        var loader:Loader = embedSWF.getChildAt(0) as Loader;

        //the content is not already loaded...
        trace(loader.content);//null


        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(){
            var swf:MovieClip = loader.content as MovieClip;
            var child:MovieClip = swf.getChildByName("$blob") as MovieClip;
            //do nasty stuff with your MovieClip !
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! Who came up with the bad idea of making embedding swfs completely different than loading them? Weird.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of this tutorial http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/flash-as3-embedding-symbols-from-external-swf-game-tutorial  there is an example of how it can be done

Comment: This is useful for symbols that are explicitly exportet to AS3 in a class. But that is exactly what I **not** want. What I want are named instances on the timeline, not their classes.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to embed the swf as an [octet stream and reconstitute its bytes.](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Embedding_assets_with_application_octet_stream-8046.html)  However, I seem to remember reading somewhere that if you just set the mimeType to "application/x-shockwave-flash", you get a MovieClip that works as normal.

Comment: When trying to load it as an octet stream (via Loader.loadBytes(new class()), it tells me that the file has some invalid data. And setting the mimeType to "application/x-shockwave-flash" simply changes nothing.